# Publishing a worker role to Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-worker-roles

Our developers need to publish a worker role to Azure and be able to get the diagnostics information if there's problem. The network admin suggests this requires the developers to log into Azure portal and upload packages and he doesn't want to do it because developers would need full admin rights.

Is this correct? This doesn't sound right. All we need to do is publish a newly created worker role to Azure -- preferrably directly from Visual Studio.

We also need to see any errors our new worker role may generate.

How should we go about it? Do we have to keep generating packages and giving them to the network admin and wait to hear from him?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you shouldn't ever be publishing into a prod environment directly from Visual Studio - it's certainly possible though.  The better bet is [deploy via a build server](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/) which is configured to deploy into a Worker Role.  This way you remove the need for a co-admin level of access for your developers.

If you want to capture errors from a Web or Worker Role (aka a Cloud Service) then you can use [Azure Diagnostics to write the logs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn186185.aspx) to an Azure Blob Storage account.